# Upgrading ExtjJS6 project to ExtJS7 - How can I make the new "Open Tooling" work with multi-app workspaces?

Tags: extjs, extjs7, extjs6.2

I have ExtJS 6.2 project with multi application workspace.
Trying to figure it out how to upgrade it to ExtJS7.
According to documentation I should use ext-gen migrate, but when running it I'm getting the following error:
'Upgrade multi-application workspace is not yet supported'

How can I make the new "Open Tooling" work with multi-app workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

Open tooling or not does not matter if you follow the following:

- download ExtJS7 (here ExtJS 7.4)
- create a new workspace
- copy content of folder `ext` to `ext-7.4.0` in your current project

workspace.json (add to frameworks)

```
       "ext74": {
            "path":"ext-7.4.0",
            "version":"7.4.0.42"
        }
```

app.json (inside your apps)

```
    "framework": "ext74",
```

go over the release notes of each version between your current version and the version you want to upgrade to. Example:

- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html

Comment: Hi Dink, thank you for the quick reply :)
In this case when we follow you instructions only the sdk was updated to version 7.
How do we import tools like webpack (that is already a part of version 7) for example?

Comment: Ahh you want to update the tooling. Sorry, missed that. I do not know. I guess you could workaround this by setup a new workspace, add the apps to the workspace.json, next copy paste the apps. ?But I am nort sure?